ansible module to merge config files
Is it possible to merge(by auto resolving conflicts) 2 config files using Ansible?
For eg,
// c1.conf
A=20
B="Hello"
D=24

// c2.conf
X=30
A=20
B="Hello2"          
C=31
E=33

//output.conf
X=30
A=20
B="Hello"           # In case of update, give priority to c1.conf
C=31                # In case of add/delete, give priority to c2.conf
E=33


I wonder why this should be closed (there are 2 votes). Would you mind commenting on the vote to close? It would help to know what you're missing.

Declare the list of files
  files:
    - /tmp/c2.conf
    - /tmp/c1.conf

and slurp them
  - slurp:
      src: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ files }}"
    register: out

Then, the declaration
  result: "{{ out.results | map(attribute='content')
                          | map('b64decode')
                          | map('community.general.jc', 'ini')
                          | combine }}"

gives
  result:
    A: '20'
    B: Hello
    C: '31'
    D: '24'
    E: '33'
    X: '30'


If you want to keep the c2 attributes only, declare the below dictionary and key list
  c2dict: "{{ out.results.0.content | b64decode
                                    | community.general.jc('ini') }}"
  c2keys: "{{ c2dict.keys() | sort }}"

give
  c2dict:
    A: '20'
    B: Hello2
    C: '31'
    E: '33'
    X: '30'

  c2keys: [A, B, C, E, X]

Then, keep the c2 keys in the result
resul2: "{{ [result] | community.general.keep_keys(target=c2keys)
                     | first }}"

gives
  resul2:
    A: '20'
    B: Hello
    C: '31'
    E: '33'
    X: '30'



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    files:
      - /tmp/c2.conf
      - /tmp/c1.conf

    result: "{{ out.results | map(attribute='content')
                            | map('b64decode')
                            | map('community.general.jc', 'ini')
                            | combine  }}"

    c2dict: "{{ out.results.0.content | b64decode
                                      | community.general.jc('ini') }}"
    c2keys: "{{ c2dict.keys() | sort }}"
    resul2: "{{ [result] | community.general.keep_keys(target=c2keys)
                         | first }}"

  tasks:

  - slurp:
      src: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ files }}"
    register: out

  - debug:
      var: out.results
  - debug:
      var: result
  - debug:
      var: c2dict
  - debug:
      var: c2keys | to_yaml 
  - debug:
      var: resul2



Hi, thanks for the response, I have community.general already installed on my controller node, but getting this error:  FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ out.results | map(attribute='content') | map('b64decode') | map('community.general.jc', 'ini') | combine  }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: You need to install "jc" as a Python library on the Ansible controller prior to running jc filter"}


ansible-galaxy collection list | grep community.general
community.general             10.0.1


You must install jc on the controller. You'll like it.

Thanks a lot for sharing the expertise!
